# chrome.socket.read gives negative error code on self-addressed message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm having problems reading a message from myself using the `chrome.socket` API. I'm creating the socket as follows:

```
chrome.socket.create('udp', {}, function (_socketInfo) {
    socketInfo = _socketInfo;
    chrome.socket.connect(socketInfo.socketId, '127.0.0.1', 12345, function () {
        poll();
    });
});
```

`poll()` simply does `chrome.socket.read(socketInfo.socketId, ...)` and calls itself at the end of the callback.

Elsewhere I have a call to `chrome.socket.write(socketInfo.socketId, data, ...)`, and the parameter supplied to the callback suggests that all the bytes in `data` were successfully written. However, while the callback to `chrome.socket.read` is indeed being called, the parameter of the callback shows a negative error code, specifically -101.

When I connect to a simple UDP echo server at a remote address, I don't have any problems writing the message and getting it back intact.

Is it even possible to send a message to oneself at the same address like this?